# MySql table auto increment stuck on 0

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've got a MySql table with an auto increment field, with the last value of 51.

I tried to insert a new row, but get the message "*failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine*". After a bit of digging I found the Auto increment value is set to 0. I then run the code:

```
ALTER TABLE `client` auto_increment = 52;
```

I get the message that the SQL query has been executed successfully. However, the Auto_increment value don't change and seems to be stuck on 0. 
I'm using phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The table became fragmented. I defragment the table with the code below, and it is now ok.

```
   ALTER TABLE `client` ENGINE = InnoDB;
```